# Cannot send notification in Laravel (lack of via() method in MailMessage)

Tags: php, laravel, email, notifications

Here's my code:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Customer extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $mail =  (new MailMessage)
            ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
            ->action('Reset Password', url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $token, false)))
            ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further  action is required.');

        $this->notify($mail);
    }


}
```

When I try to run it I get error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage::via()

I have no idea what I am supposed to add here to make it work. The Customer Class has email column in database if it helps.

Comment: Your `MailMessage` class should implement `via` method

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

create a sendPasswordResetNotification class using artisan

```
php artisan make:notification sendPasswordResetNotification
```

sendPasswordResetNotification class :

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class sendPasswordResetNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $token;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $mail =  (new MailMessage)
            ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
            ->action('Reset Password', url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)))
            ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further  action is required.');
    }

}
```

Now your customer model look like this:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Notifications\sendPasswordResetNotification;

class Customer extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
       $this->notify(new sendPasswordResetNotification($token));
    }
```

}

> second way to send a mail by using controller

```
Customer::find($id)->notify(new sendPasswordResetNotification($token));
```

Comment: but can I do this with MailMessage class? It is Laravel built-in and is used in default Auth. I would like to use that.

Comment: MailMessage class i don't know . but my way u send notification to other drivers also my option it is best way to sending notification.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, that helped. Thanks!